# Почему не работает флекс?

Tags: css

```css
.clocks {
  width: 860px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.clock-card {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #FDFDFB;
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  &__banner {
    & .banner-title {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
  & .card-img {
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  &:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  & .card-title {
    @include font-family-normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 21px;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    color: #444240;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  & .card-price {
    @include font-family-normal;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #636261;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.card-icons {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  & .add-card-favorites {
    background-image: url(../img/heart.svg);
    right: 55px;
    &:hover {
      background-image: url(../img/heart_active.svg);
      filter: none;
    }
    &__active {
      background-image: url(../img/heart_active.svg);
    }
  }
  & .add-card-basket {
    background-image: url(../img/basket.svg);
    right: 20px;
  }
  & .card-icon {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    background-position: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    z-index: 10;
    &:hover {
      filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="сlocks">
  <a href="" class="clock-card">
    <div class="card-icons">
      <button class="add-card-favorites card-icon" data-id="card-1"></button>
      <button class="add-card-basket card-icon"></button>
    </div>
    <h2 class="card-title">
      TECHNE
    </h2>
    <p class="card-price">
      22 700 &#8381
    </p>
    <img class="card-img" src="img/watch_1.png" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="" class="clock-card">
    <div class="card-icons">
      <button class="add-card-favorites card-icon" data-id="card-2"></button>
      <button class="add-card-basket card-icon"></button>
    </div>
    <h2 class="card-title">
      TECHNE
    </h2>
    <p class="card-price">
      22 700 &#8381
    </p>
    <img class="card-img" src="img/watch_2.png" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="" class="clock-card">
    <div class="card-icons">
      <button class="add-card-favorites card-icon" data-id="card-3"></button>
      <button class="add-card-basket card-icon"></button>
    </div>
    <h2 class="card-title">
      TECHNE
    </h2>
    <p class="card-price">
      22 700 &#8381
    </p>
    <img class="card-img" src="img/watch_3.png" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="" class="clock-card">
    <div class="card-icons">
      <button class="add-card-favorites card-icon"></button>
      <button class="add-card-basket card-icon"></button>
    </div>
    <h2 class="card-title">
      TECHNE
    </h2>
    <p class="card-price">
      22 700 &#8381
    </p>
    <img class="card-img" src="img/watch_4.png" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="" class="clock-card">
    <div class="card-icons">
      <button class="add-card-favorites  add-card-favorites__active card-icon"></button>
      <button class="add-card-basket card-icon"></button>
    </div>
    <h2 class="card-title">
      TECHNE
    </h2>
    <p class="card-price">
      22 700 &#8381
    </p>
    <img class="card-img" src="img/watch_5.png" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="" class="clock-card">
    <h2>
      TECHNE
    </h2>
    <img class="card-img" src="img/banner_catalog.png" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="" class="clock-card">
    <div class="card-icons">
      <button class="add-card-favorites card-icon"></button>
      <button class="add-card-basket card-icon"></button>
    </div>
    <h2 class="card-title">
      TECHNE
    </h2>
    <p class="card-price">
      22 700 &#8381
    </p>
    <img class="card-img" src="img/watch_6.png" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="" class="clock-card">
    <div class="card-icons">
      <button class="add-card-favorites card-icon"></button>
      <button class="add-card-basket card-icon"></button>
    </div>
    <h2 class="card-title">
      TECHNE
    </h2>
    <p class="card-price">
      22 700 &#8381
    </p>
    <img class="card-img" src="img/watch_7.png" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="" class="clock-card">
    <div class="card-icons">
      <button class="add-card-favorites card-icon"></button>
      <button class="add-card-basket card-icon"></button>
    </div>
    <h2 class="card-title">
      TECHNE
    </h2>
    <p class="card-price">
      22 700 &#8381
    </p>
    <img class="card-img" src="img/watch_8.png" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="" class="clock-card">
    <div class="card-icons">
      <button class="add-card-favorites card-icon"></button>
      <button class="add-card-basket card-icon"></button>
    </div>
    <h2 class="card-title">
      TECHNE
    </h2>
    <p class="card-price">
      22 700 &#8381
    </p>
    <img class="card-img" src="img/watch_9.png" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="" class="clock-card">
    <div class="card-icons">
      <button class="add-card-favorites card-icon"></button>
      <button class="add-card-basket card-icon"></button>
    </div>
    <h2 class="card-title">
      TECHNE
    </h2>
    <p class="card-price">
      22 700 &#8381
    </p>
    <img class="card-img" src="img/watch_10.png" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="" class="clock-card">
    <div class="card-icons">
      <button class="add-card-favorites card-icon"></button>
      <button class="add-card-basket card-icon"></button>
    </div>
    <h2 class="card-title">
      TECHNE
    </h2>
    <p class="card-price">
      22 700 &#8381
    </p>
    <img class="card-img" src="img/watch_11.png" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: потому что не надо писать русскими и английскими буквами одно слова.Обратите внимание на `clocks` в html и css

Comment: Когда даю флекс,то контент внутри карточки ужимается. Что это может быть?

Comment: потому что вы пытаетесь впихнуть 3000 пикелей, в 860, интересно как) браузер начинает сжимать до минимума блоки чтобы вместить, но увы. в результате остаётся минимальная ширина.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: @DmitriiSedov, кириллица работает, не уверен правда что во всех браузерах. ([линк](https://jsfiddle.net/CbIPoK2513/0o8mqes7/))

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 да при условии что и там и там, одинаково, а у автора в html русские + англ а в css только англ!